# Installing tinymce on my pages

Tags: tinymce

I have installed tinymce. Basically, when I go into my cms I make the changes. For example, making the text red. In the edit page it works fine, but when I go into my website, the changes do not appear. Furthermore, when I click on "submit" in my cms and then re-edit the content (by clicking on edit), the changes are gone. As if I have never tried changing anything. I'm an integrator (as I'm just starting out), not a programmer, so I have trouble understanding what I am missing or what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: I can use the bold tool and works fine. But colouring for example doesn't wanna seem to work. My text does not stay red :(

This is the code I have on my edit page:

```
<head>
<script src="../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script>


    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        skin : "o2k7",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,inlinepopups,autosave",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the method tinymce uses to color parts of the text.
Use firebug or a similar tool to check out how tinymce styles it and what you get on the website. There will be a difference between the two of 'em.